# CSS alternative/equivalent of display: table, table-row-group, table-row, and table-cell?

Tags: css, itext, css-tables, itext7

I have strange problem to overcome which I'll explain why I need to overcome it below if you're interested. But, essentially, I need to apply CSS that gets the EXACT same effect as each of the following on Divs :

```
display: table;
display: table-row-group;
display: table-row;
display: table-cell;
```

Perhaps, a combination of a few different CSS attributes could achieve the same thing (not just a display property, but alignment, height/width properties, etc)
Any help would be much appreciated.

Now, the reason in case you're interested: I am working on a .NET MVC app that generates a PDF from a View. The previous developer used a tool called Rotavia to achieve this and laid out a whole header section using a table. A new client requirement is that our PDF's be accessible/508 compliant. So, we have had to switch from Rotavia to iText HTML to PDF. This section does not perform the function of a table and, according to 508 rules, should not be a table. So I switched the table, tbody, tr and td elements to divs with display: table, table-row-group, table-row, and table-cell respectively and the layout looks essentially the same which is what I wanted. HOWEVER, iText still converts these to table elements (tags in the PDF) which is very, very annoying. In my opinion, it should be obvious if I'm using a div with these display properties, I'm trying to eliminate the use of a table but get the same layout effect. I've tried a number of different CSS alternatives, but everything messes up the layout.

Comment: Why would CSS provide two methods to do the exact same thing? And if it did, why would iText treat them differently?

Comment: Is this intended to be a thematically separate question from [your previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589510/itext-7-accessible-pdfs-from-html-how-do-i-avoid-table-tag-when-using-display)? This is still an iText-specific issue, right?

Comment: Yes, it is similar, and I dropped this into the previous question. There were two questions in the previous one and the main one was asking if there was a way around this behavior in iText. I asked this one as a side note. Since there are a lot more CSS experts out there than iText experts and my question didn't receive any answers, I thought I'd ask this direct CSS question.

Comment: @Alohci : I believe, although I'm not 100% sure, that iText sees this particular CSS attribute and treats it as a table.

Comment: @Alohci : Maybe nearly the exact same thing? A combination of a few different CSS attributes could achieve the same thing (not just a display attribute, but alignment, height/width properties, etc)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the reason why you have to use iText. Aren't there other PDF generators that don't have the same problem?

Comment: Might be worth the time to post a question to iText asking if there is a way to disable the table conversion

Comment: @MrLister : If there are, let me know. It has to do with 508/accessibility requirements. Rotavia, which uses wkhtmltopdf.exe , will not insert PDF tags [link](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1605) and will not pick up on Title, language or alt attributes on images and other things. It needs to be a .NET tool that does use a separate web service like PDFreactor (I think the Java version of PDFreactor does not use a web service, but the .NET version does). Even PDFreactor may have the same issues, not sure. We also have committed to commercial licenses of iText

Comment: @Huangism : Their website doesn't seem to have a "Contact us" or support option for Developers... it's all about purchasing licenses, or business questions... but I'll take another look and maybe just contact them through that channel anyway

Comment: @TamerRifai try https://developers.itextpdf.com/ you might still have to poke around though

Comment: https://itextpdf.com/support is where you need to go. It lists the different types of questions you may have, and where to ask them.

Comment: @TamerRifai if you have purchased a license, then you can open a ticket in the iText Jira. Support on Stack Overflow is voluntary and is not guaranteed.