# iText 7 PDF accessibility: set cell scope

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext7

I'm converting HTML to PDF using pdfHTML add-on in iTExt 7. I wanted to create accessible pdf. To fix the pdf accessibility issue followed below link.
[iText 7 PDF accessibility: "Table header cell has no associated subcells"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771422/itext-7-pdf-accessibility-table-header-cell-has-no-associated-subcells)
When rowspan is 1 and colspan is 1, I could set the scope of the cell. But when the colspan is 2 and rowspan is 1, scope,column isn't applied to the cell. I followed same steps in the above url. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you using pdfHTML 2.0.2+? [This commit](https://github.com/itext/i7n-pdfhtml/commit/48a3823a479ea6ce8f2d78bd09b8cd45ba8f569c) which I wrote for the user in your linked question will also set the role of `colgroup` or `rowgroup` as per the [W3 Schools page on <th> scope](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_th_scope.asp)

Comment: I'm using pdfHTML 2.0.0.0. It seems that version doesn't support olgroup or rowgroup.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The fix was implemented in 2.0.2.

Comment: Can I know  whether this scenario can implement in pdfHTML 2.0.0.0 or not  ?

Comment: Only if you manually port [the commit](https://github.com/itext/i7n-pdfhtml/commit/48a3823a479ea6ce8f2d78bd09b8cd45ba8f569c) into a [custom tag worker](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-5-custom-tag-workers-and-css-appliers). That is, override the `ThTagWorker` with a custom one to act the same as the one in 2.0.2.